# Execute function only once even though radio buttons are selected multiple times

Tags: jquery, html

In my code below there are four radio buttons. If you click on one of them, it will execute a function to activate the "next" button. Upon clicking "next", the div will slide.

If I keep clicking other options/radio buttons multiple times, the function will also execute multiple times and the div keeps on sliding. How do I prevent this? I only want the div to slide once even though I selected multiple radio buttons.

JSfiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lqjy6vja/

```
<div>
<ul id="orderform">
    <li class="formitem">
        <input type="radio" name="jcolour" id="jcolour1" value="Black/Red Jersey" /><label for="jcolour1">Black/Red</label><br/><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="jcolour" id="jcolour2" value="Black/White Jersey" /><label for="jcolour2">Black/White</label><br/><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="jcolour" id="jcolour3" value="White/Black Jersey" /><label for="jcolour3">White/Black</label><br/><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="jcolour" id="jcolour4" value="Custom Jersey" /><label for="jcolour4">Custom Jersey</label>
        <div class="nextbtn">Next ></div>
    </li>
    <li class="formitem">2</li>
</ul>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nextbtn").prop('disabled', true).css("opacity","0.4");
    var winwidth=$(window).width();
    $("#orderform li").width(winwidth);
    $('input:radio[name=jcolour]').change(function () {
    $(this).closest(".formitem").find(".nextbtn").css("opacity","1");
    $(".nextbtn").click(function(){
        $("#orderform").animate({
            marginLeft: '-='+winwidth
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: $("#orderform").stop().animate({...

Comment: @nevermind I think ccasado's answer is the right aproach. I would not recomend using stop in this case

Comment: @frikinside hi, I have tested both nevermind's and ccasado's answers and they work. But I'd just like to know why using stop is not good?

Comment: @deew because stoping the animation does not solve the real problem. Like ccasado said you are setting a new click event handler on every radio button change event, and that's the real problem. Just stopping the animation is like to break a window with a stone instead of open it. You get the fresh air, but is not the right way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you set the `click` event for each option `change` event.
So, when you `click` the div every attached `click` events execute. 
You need to set it only once putting the click event handler **outside** the `change` event:

```
$(".nextbtn").prop('disabled', true).css("opacity","0.4");
var winwidth=$(window).width();
$("#orderform li").width(winwidth);

$('input:radio[name=jcolour]').change(function () {
    $(this).closest(".formitem").find(".nextbtn").css("opacity","1");
});
$(".nextbtn").click(function(){
    $("#orderform").animate({
        marginLeft: '-='+winwidth
    });
});
```

Here is the updated [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqjy6vja/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Do like this , It will work.
```

---

```
            <div>
                    <ul id="orderform">
                        <li class="formitem">
                            <input type="radio" name="jcolour" class="jcolour" id="jcolour1" value="Black/Red Jersey"
                                isslide="false" /><label for="jcolour1">Black/Red</label><br />
                            <br />
                            <input type="radio" name="jcolour" class="jcolour" id="jcolour2" value="Black/White Jersey"
                                isslide="false" /><label for="jcolour2">Black/White</label><br />
                            <br />
                            <input type="radio" name="jcolour" class="jcolour" id="jcolour3" value="White/Black Jersey"
                                isslide="false" /><label for="jcolour3">White/Black</label><br />
                            <br />
                            <input type="radio" name="jcolour" class="jcolour" id="jcolour4" value="Custom Jersey"
                                isslide="false" /><label for="jcolour4">Custom Jersey</label>
                            <div class="nextbtn">
                                Next ></div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="formitem">2</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>


            <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $(".nextbtn").prop('disabled', true).css("opacity", "0.4");
                        var winwidth = $(window).width();
                        $("#orderform li").width(winwidth);
                        $('input:radio[name=jcolour]').change(function () {
                            debugger;
                            var slideval = $('.jcolour').attr('isslide');
                            if (slideval == "false") {
                                $('.jcolour').attr('isslide', 'true');
                                $(this).closest(".formitem").find(".nextbtn").prop('disabled', false).css("opacity", "1");
                                $(".nextbtn").click(function () {
                                    $("#orderform").animate({
                                        marginLeft: '-=' + winwidth
                                    });
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```